# Client credentials flow does not work with identity scope

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, identityserver3

I use Identity server 3 for identity service.
Today, I understood that in Client credentials flow it is only possible to get access token if you provide a resource scope. For example suppose we run this request:

```
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:client
client_secret:secret
scope:test
```

if we defined scope test as a Resource scope we can get access token. but if the test scope be an Identity scope. server returns error message `invalid_scope`.

Could anybody explain why is that? Does it mean that I do not have access to profile and openid using a client token?